# Clearing contents of dependent drop down lists in merged cells using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple dependent drop down lists and I want to clear the contents of child drop down lists when the parent content is changed by the user.
I found the following sample code,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'clear contents of dependent cells
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case 2  'clear columns C and D
                Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), _
                  Target.Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents
            Case 3  'clear column D
                Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End Select
    End If

exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub

End Sub
```

But it does not work for me and I assume that it is due to one or both reasons:

1. my drop down lists are in merged cells;
2. I use a Right To Left worksheet.

I'd like to know what changes I should make to the code so it will work.

Thank You.

Comment: Note: Instead of `On Error Resume Next` you should use `On Error Goto exitHandler` otherwise this is no proper error handling. • And there are 2 `End Sub` in your code.

Comment: Can you explain or show the layout of your spreadsheet. I think youll need to use the `MergeArea` property and then `ClearContents` and if you mean you need to clear contents to the left of the changed column then your ofssets will need to be negative

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
@Peh , I'll change the `On Error Resume Next`. The second `End Sub` is by accident.

@maxhob17 , The layout of the spreadsheet is from Right To Left. It means the first column (column A) is in the right hand (Hebrew language). Can you give me an example of how `MergeArea` property should be applied in this case?

Comment: @MrHalili, sure I think you would stick it on the end of the range before the `ClearContents` like so: `Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, 2)).MergeArea.ClearContents`

Comment: @maxhob17 Thank you! it works very good! But I have to eliminate `Range(Target...` and for every offset write separate code line i.e.
`Target.Offset(0, 1).MergeArea.ClearContents
  Target.Offset(0, 2).MergeArea.ClearContents`
any Idea why the Range(Target... does not work?